# Displaying data from a column's Table to a View

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

As the title says I am trying to pass data from my table to a view . What I have done so far :

Controller

```
public function getData(){
  $fName = DB::table('users')->select('org_name')->get();
  return view('multi',compact('fName'));
}
```

my route

```
Route::get('/createteams','MultiSelectController@getData')->name('multi');
```

one row of the form that I need the data to display as multi select

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="org_select" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Select up to 4 Orgs') }}<br>Hold Ctrl For multiple selection</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <select id="org_select" multiple class="form-control" name="org_select" value="{{ old('org_select') }}" autocomplete="org_select">
      @foreach ($fName as $name)
        {{$name->org_name}}
        {{$user->name}}
      @endforeach
    </select>
    @error('org_select')
      <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
      </span>
    @enderror
  </div>
</div>
```

Error i am getting :

> Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
>   Undefined variable: fName (View: C:\Users\rippe\emindspage\resources\views\teams\createteams.blade.php)

Comment: Why your function `getData` is inside  `{}` ?

Comment: its inside the Controller class

Comment: You are not passing `$fName` to your view.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that as a select option, the results should be inside `<option></option>` tags:

```
@foreach ($fName as $name)
    <option value="{{$name->org_name}}"> {{$user->name}} </option>
@endforeach
```

I can't see that `$user` is coming from backend so maybe you'll get an error there.

Comment: ye i replaced that $user but thats not the problem . fname is still not defined.I dont know why but my controller doesnt send the fname array to the view

Comment: Try changing your return statement for this: `return view('multi',['fName' => $fName]);`

Comment: unfortunately i get the same error

Comment: can you add to your answer the error you are getting?

Comment: Edited and added.

Comment: found the error i didnt   incude 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

Comment: Nice, i'm glad i worked!

Comment: i am kinda new to stackoverflow, do i answer my own question and mark it as the best answer or ?